# Can I put "will" in stead of "should" in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

Helen has been studying hard for the exam, so she **should** pass.

Can I put "will" in stead of "should" in this sentence? If so, is it natural and what's the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"will" and "should" have different meanings.

Grammatically both are possible here, but "will" expresses greater confidence in the future outcome.  "She will pass" = "I am certain", "She should pass" = "I expect her to pass, if everything else is fair."